# Testing Significant Differences Between

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

I have a set of variables, say different Jeep models like Compass, Wrangler, Cherokee ...., and for each a respondent does a rating from Very Satisfied - Very Unsatisfied (Ordinal from 1 to 6) and I want to do a test of sig between the mean rating for each model.

To further clarify, the models are variables in an SPSS data file and for each model, a respondent (cases) does a rating thus each data cell represents the person's rating, e.g. a 3, for that model, e.g., Compass

This is a cross-posting for another stats forum so where the solution comes from will also post on the other site.

Hope clear and thanks
W

Comment: Have you considered the Kruskal-Wallis test? This is a non-parametric test that is suitable for likert scale data like you have.